# "Method not found" error with MongoDB.MongoCursor

Tags: mongodb, tracking

I have problem with MongoDB.Driver.MongoCursor. When I want to set tracking I get an error:

> Method not found: 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoCursor`1 Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbCollection.FindAs(MongoDB.Driver.IMongoQuery)'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoCursor`1 Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbCollection.FindAs(MongoDB.Driver.IMongoQuery)'.

I have no idea how I can solve this problem...

Sitecore 8.2
MongoDB 3.4.7

Resolve problem:

The problem was the bad version of the sitecore libraries downloaded from nuget.

Comment: Include information on Sitecore version and MongoDB version in use, please.

Answer (score 3):

Sitecore 8.2 is not supporting MongoDB 3.4.7 yet, Latest version of mongoDB supported is 3.2.1
See supported versions table here : https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/633863

Comment: This may be a problem with stability of operation, but evidently here can not find a method. I'm using MongoDB.Driver and MongoDB.Bson in version 2.4.4.0 and 1.10.0.62. The method that is calling is in the MongoDB.Driver.Legacy library, which unfortunately is unsigned after downloading with Nuget.

Comment: I change version MongoDB on 3.2.1, but the effect is the same

Comment: @JanNowak What are you referring to about "1.10.0.62" ?

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore 8.2 update 5 is not supported at this moment.
Update 5 uses Mongo 2.4.4 but Habitat uses 1.10.

Try to install 8.2 update 4 and Web Forms for marketers update 1.